# "Multiple widgets used the same GlobalKey" error in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]

I'm getting an error like the one in the picture. I'm confused because I'm not setting up `GlobalKey` on every page. I just made a `GlobalKey` on `main.dart` for this:

```dart
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> with WidgetsBindingObserver {
  StreamController<bool> _showLockScreenStream = StreamController();
  StreamSubscription _showLockScreenSubs;
  GlobalKey<NavigatorState> _navigatorKey = GlobalKey();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);

    _showLockScreenSubs = _showLockScreenStream.stream.listen((bool show){
      if (mounted && show) {
        _showLockScreenDialog();
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
    _showLockScreenSubs?.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  // Listen for when the app enter in background or foreground state.
  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    if (state == AppLifecycleState.resumed) {
      // user returned to our app, we push an event to the stream
      _showLockScreenStream.add(true);
    } else if (state == AppLifecycleState.inactive) {
      // app is inactive
    } else if (state == AppLifecycleState.paused) {
      // user is about quit our app temporally
    } else if (state == AppLifecycleState.suspending) {
      // app suspended (not used in iOS)
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      navigatorKey: _navigatorKey,
      ...
    );
  }

  void _showLockScreenDialog() {
    _navigatorKey.currentState.
        .pushReplacement(new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return PassCodeScreen();
    }));
  }
}
```

I've tried to remove the `GlobalKey _navigatorKey` but the error still appears.

The error appears when switching pages. Is there anyone who can help me?

Comment: use static/constant for your key.

Comment: static final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> _navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>(); does not work

Answer (score -1):

There are many kinds of `Key`s. But the `GlobalKey` allows access to the state of a widget (if it's a `StatefulWigdet`).

Then, if you use the same `GlobalKey` for many of them, there is a conflict with their `State`s.

In addition, they must be of the same type due to its specification:

```dart
abstract class GlobalKey<T extends State<StatefulWidget>> extends Key {
  // ...
  void _register(Element element) {
    assert(() {
      if (_registry.containsKey(this)) {
        assert(element.widget != null);
        final Element oldElement = _registry[this]!;
        assert(oldElement.widget != null);
        assert(element.widget.runtimeType != oldElement.widget.runtimeType);
        _debugIllFatedElements.add(oldElement);
      }
      return true;
    }());
    _registry[this] = element;
  }
  // ...
}
```

This fragment of code shows that in debug mode, there is an assertion for ensuring that there isn't any other `GlobalState` of the same type previously registered.

Comment: the problem is I only use GlobalKey in main.dart like the example I gave above. and I've tried to delete the GlobalKey but the error still appears. actually at the beginning I made it there was no problem, but suddenly the error appeared, I didn't change anything in my code. as I remember, I changed my flutter channel from master to stable and updated the package

Comment: Could you provide the code where the global key is used?

Comment: I have explained the code in the question above